# How to run app in Kiosk mode with Wear 2.0?

Tags: android-wear, kiosk-mode

I'm trying to get a Wear 2.0 (stand-alone) app to run in kiosk mode, but when I try

`adb shell dpm set-device-owner <myComponent>`

I get:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to set the device owner because this device has already paired
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1692)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
    at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.setDeviceOwner(IDevicePolicyManager.java:4707)
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.runSetDeviceOwner(Dpm.java:148)
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.onRun(Dpm.java:96)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.main(Dpm.java:41)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:262)`

I also tried by copying a file to `/data/system/device_owner.xml` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358689/how-to-use-android-l-preview-task-locking), but also without success.

Note: on a mobile I have successfully entered kiosk mode using `adb shell dpm set-device-owner <myComponent>`.

Anyone knows a way to enter kiosk mode using Wear 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Self-answering for now, this seems to be an issue in Wear 2.0 - see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=232628

I'd be happy to know of any workarounds though!